# iPhone:Convert NSMutableArray to NSData with stored & retrieved issue

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdata, store, nsmutabledictionary

I am facing a problem, that is to convert `NSMutableArray` into `NSData` and stored & retrieved that array into `rootviewcontroller` so please give me idea. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
appDelegate = (FindNearMeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

appDelegate.isCategoryCell = TRUE;

appDelegate.isButton = NO;

NSString *categoryStr = categoryName.text;
NSLog(@"Category Name:--->%@",categoryStr);

appDelegate.categoryData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 categoryStr, @"name",image ,@"image", nil];

[appDelegate.categories addObject:appDelegate.categoryData];
NSLog(@"Category Data:--->%@",appDelegate.categories);
```

I am initialize nsmutablearray (appDelegate.categories) and nsmutabledictionary in appdelegate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the data is pure array/dictionary data, with only strings and numbers, convert it to JSON and store the JSON.

Comment: @DanielRHicks name & image which is pick from uiimagepickercontroller so any idea?

Comment: You can convert a `UIImage` into `NSData` via `NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(aImage);`. Hope that Helps!

Comment: thanks a lot but how can i store image???

Comment: No its not help me so is any idea???

Comment: Maybe convert the image with the above function from MSgamble, then convert that to characters with, say, base64 encoding, then JSON.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to save your images and retrieve them. You can convert your image to `NSData` using one of the 2 methods, `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` depending on the type of the image. You can then save this data-

```
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES]; //imagePath is where you want to save it. Most likely it contains the value of the name key in your dictionary.
```